# How to send data to Redis from a Resque worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I'm trying to create a resque worker that does some webscraping as a background job.  The worker receives the URL for a website's homepage, does some webscraping, and then stores the results in Redis, where it's meant to persist for five minutes.

Does the code below look like it should accomplish what I've described above?

```
class TrialScraper
  @queue = :trial_scraper_queue
  def self.perform(homepage)
    hashed_site_data = 
      {
        :homepage =>
          {
            :url => homepage,
            :title => download_title(homepage),
            :meta_tags => download_robots_tags(homepage) 
          },
        :robots_file => download_robots_file(homepage),
      }
         p hashed_site_data #just to make sure it's working
    REDIS.setex(homepage, 60*5, hashed_site_data.to_json)
  end
```

Right now, this doesn't even appear Resque's web interface.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I presume that the problem lies in sending the data to REDIS, but I'm not sure.

EDIT: Just to clarify, here's some more detail.  What I would of the worker above is that it appears as a job in Resque's web interface.

The end result of my code should really just be that some a key value pair is sent to redis (outside of Resque).  But when I'm in the redis client and I list all the keys, I don't see the key listed anywhere.  But I should see the homepage listed there alongside the other keys.

Comment: What exactly does not appear in the Resque web interface? Your job or what or the results that you're storing? If the latter than those result are arbitrary and outside the scope of Resque and it has no knowledge of any *other* data you store in Redis.

Comment: I added a bit more detail to my post in response to your comment.

Comment: Maybe it does appear in the Resque web interface but its so short lived (fast executing) that you dont even see it between refreshes? Also, is the job running in the context of your Rails app - if so put some `Rails.logger.info` lines in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently written a project that writes to a Resque queue & then when the job queue is processed it writes a result out to the same Redis store, so it is possible :)

If you're not seeing the job in the Resque web interface then you're most likely not enqueueing the job?

e.g/

```
ok = Resque.enqueue(TrialScraper, homepage)
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: I think the job is getting queued.  I have this line in the worker `p hashed_site_data #just to make sure it's working` and it will output the hashed_site_data to the tab where running the resque:work rake task.  So I believe that means that everything right up until I send the data to Redis is working.